# Vertically and horizontally align div into parent div

Tags: html, web-development, css

I'm new in the web development industry and I struggle to vertically and horizontally align a child div in a parent div. I'm trying to build a homepage with a full-width image with a slogan in the very middle of that image. This is my first attempt:

HTML:

```
<div class="img">
   <div class="text">Here is my slogan</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border-width: 0px;
    background-image: url("picture-1.jpg");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-color: black;
    min-height: 1024px;
}
.text {
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
height: 300px;
padding: 175px;
```

}

I'm sure this is noobish code, but I'm a newcomer in this industry. Could you help me, please?

Update: I made a picture of what I intend: [image]

Comment: Flexbox takes care of this easily and has quite good coverage these days see here: http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Comment: This question should have been migrated to [so]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways that this can be achieved but the one I find most useful is to change the div display to a table cell as table cells support vertical alignment.

As an adjustment to your sample code...

**HTML**

```
<div class="img">
   <div class="text">Here is my slogan</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.img {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border-width: 0px;
    background-image: url("picture-1.jpg");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-color: black;
    min-height: 1024px;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.text {
    text-align: center;
    height: 300px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Note the addition of `display: table` to the `.img` class and the addition of `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle` to the `.text` class.

This has been tested and saved at https://jsfiddle.net/wLm5zjwx/

Comment: Putting this on in my library of code.

Answer (score 1):

Try CSS Flexbox: `display: flex; align-items: center;`